# Integrate silex with Redbean orm

Tags: orm, silex, redbean

Any one have idea how to integrate Red bean ORM in Silex. Any examples/docs available.Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very basic setup shown below.

Since Redbean provides a static class facade `RedBean_Facade`, which in the docs is referred to as `R`, there's little need to register it as a service of the Silex Application.

You should ideally install both Silex and Redbean with Composer. On the Redbean Github page it tells you how to use it with Composer.

```php
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Silex\Application;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use RedBean_Facade as R;

$app = new Application();

$app['db.connection.default.driver'] = "mysql";
$app['db.connection.default.host'] = "localhost";
$app['db.connection.default.name'] = "mydatabase";
$app['db.connection.default.user'] = "user";
$app['db.connection.default.password'] = "password";

$app['db.connection.default.rsn'] = $app->share(function () use ($app) {
    return sprintf('%s:host=%s;dbname=%s',
        $app['db.connection.default.driver'],
        $app['db.connection.default.host'],
        $app['db.connection.default.name']
    );
});

R::setup(
    $app['db.connection.default.rsn'],
    $app['db.connection.default.user'],
    $app['db.connection.default.password']
);

$app->get('/article/{id}/show', function ($id) {
    $article = R::load('article', $id );

    // do something with $article, then
    // return an HTML page of the article.
});

$app->get('/article/new', function () {
    // return an HTML page with a form that contains
    // input fields with HTML name attributes set to
    // 'title' and 'body' for example.
});

$app->post('/article/new', function (Request $request) use ($app) {
    $article = R::dispense('article');

    $article->title = $request->request->get('title');
    $article->body = $request->request->get('body');

    $id = R::store($article);

    return $app->redirect(sprintf('/article/%d/show', $id));
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Should I give in evry page this connection strings ? Is there anything like parmeters.yml?

Comment: In Silex, not really as everything can be in one single PHP file like the code in my answer, for example. However, you can install the Symfony Yaml component and parse your own file like `$parameters = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('parameters.yml'))`. When you say every page do you mean every route/controller action that renders a page?

Comment: I just realised you post the comment a while ago. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

I made a [Service Provider](https://github.com/ivoba/redbean-service-provider) for RedBean in Silex.
Just put this in your composer.json and update:

```
"ivoba/redbean-service-provider": "dev-master"
```

Then register the provider:

```
$app->register(new Ivoba\Silex\RedBeanServiceProvider(), array('db.options' => array( 'dsn' => 'sqlite:/tmp/db.sqlite' )));
```

Use it like this:

```
use RedBean_Facade as R;
...
$app['db']; //call once to init RedBean
...
$e = R::findAll('table',' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2');
```

Comment: Your service provider does not work the newest version of redbean when I tried to add it.  Will you add support for version 4.0+? of redbean?

Comment: i added 4.0 support now, in version ~2.0

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I also wrote a [RedBean service provider for Silex](http://www.zaibatsu.fr/articles/use-redbean-orm-with-silex-micro-framework). It allows you to use RedBean as an instance instead of a static Facade (which I personnally dislike) :

```
$book = $app['redbean']->dispense('book');
$book->title = 'PHP for dummies';
$app['redbean']->store($book);
```

RedBean is thus available all around your Silex app without having to `use Redbean_Facade` in every file.

It's still a work in progress, all contributions are much appreciated :)

Comment: Does your provider work with version 4.0 of redbean?

Answer (score 0):

I did it just today.
Just load by Composer both libraries (Silex and RedBean). Make sure to have Fat Silex release to stay secure.
And.. to make an elegant way you should make a controller that load RedBean and than make controller as service provider, then you will have your RedBean setup avaible every where in your app.
I will be make next days RedBeanServiceProvider.